# Blank spaces in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I am trying to compile the following example code, which I embedded in a subroutine:

```
      module wallforcing
      use shared_module
      contains

      subroutine phicontrol

        EXTERNAL  FEX
        INTEGER  IOPT, IOUT, ISTATE, ITASK, ITOL, IWORK(23), LIW, LRW,
     &              MF, NEQ
        DOUBLE PRECISION  ATOL(3), RTOL, RWORK(58), T, TOUT, Y(3)
        NEQ = 3
        Y(1) = 1.D0
        Y(2) = 0.D0
        Y(3) = 0.D0
        T = 0.D0
        TOUT = .4D0
        ITOL = 2
        RTOL = 1.D-4
        ATOL(1) = 1.D-6
        ATOL(2) = 1.D-10
        ATOL(3) = 1.D-6
        ITASK = 1
        ISTATE = 1
        IOPT = 0
        LRW = 58
        LIW = 23
        MF = 21
        DO 40 IOUT = 1,12
          CALL DLSODE (FEX, NEQ, Y, T, TOUT, ITOL, RTOL, ATOL, ITASK,
     &              ISTATE, IOPT, RWORK, LRW, IWORK, LIW, JEX, MF)
          WRITE(6,20)  T, Y(1), Y(2), Y(3)
    20 FORMAT(' At t =',D12.4,'   y =',3D14.6)
            IF (ISTATE .LT. 0)  GO TO 80
    40 TOUT = TOUT*10.D0
          WRITE(6,60)  IWORK(11), IWORK(12), IWORK(13)
    60 FORMAT(/' No. steps =',i4,',  No. f-s =',i4,',  No. J-s =',i4)
          STOP
    80 WRITE(6,90)  ISTATE
    90 FORMAT(///' Error halt.. ISTATE =',I3)
          STOP
        END
C
C        SUBROUTINE  JEX (NEQ, T, Y, ML, MU, PD, NRPD)
C        INTEGER  NEQ, ML, MU, NRPD
C        DOUBLE PRECISION  T, Y(3), PD(NRPD,3)
C        PD(1,1) = -.04D0
C        PD(1,2) = 1.D4*Y(3)
C        PD(1,3) = 1.D4*Y(2)
C        PD(2,1) = .04D0
C        PD(2,3) = -PD(1,3)
C        PD(3,2) = 6.D7*Y(2)
C        PD(2,2) = -PD(1,2) - PD(3,2)
C        RETURN
C        END
C
c       return
       end subroutine phicontrol
C        SUBROUTINE  FEX (NEQ, T, Y, YDOT)
C        INTEGER  NEQ
C        DOUBLE PRECISION  T, Y(3), YDOT(3)
C        YDOT(1) = -.04D0*Y(1) + 1.D4*Y(2)*Y(3)
C        YDOT(3) = 3.D7*Y(2)*Y(2)
C        YDOT(2) = -YDOT(1) - YDOT(3)
C        RETURN
C        END
       end module wallforcing
```

I get a bunch of errors, which I think are related to a bad treatment of blank spaces:

```
wallcontrol.f(35): error #5082: Syntax error, found INTEGER_CONSTANT '0' when ex   pecting one of: ( * ) :: , <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; + . - % (/ [ : ] /) . ' ** / ...
        20 FORMAT(' At t =',D12.4,'   y =',3D14.6)
---------^
wallcontrol.f(35): error #5082: Syntax error, found REAL_CONSTANT '.4' when expe   cting one of: ( * ) :: , + . - % : . ** / // .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. ...
        20 FORMAT(' At t =',D12.4,'   y =',3D14.6)
-------------------------------^
wallcontrol.f(35): error #5082: Syntax error, found REAL_CONSTANT '.6' when expe   cting one of: * ) :: , <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; + . - (/ [ : ] /) ' ** / // > .LT. .   ..
        20 FORMAT(' At t =',D12.4,'   y =',3D14.6)
-----------------------------------------------^
wallcontrol.f(60): error #6786: This is an invalid statement; an END [MODULE] st   atement is required.
       end subroutine phicontrol
-------^
wallcontrol.f(60): error #6785: This name does not match the unit name.   [PHICO   NTROL]
       end subroutine phicontrol
----------------------^
wallcontrol.f(44): error #6378: SUBROUTINE must be present on the end-subroutine   -stmt of an internal or module subroutine
        END
^
wallcontrol.f(31): error #6321: An unterminated block exists.
        DO 40 IOUT = 1,12
^
wallcontrol.f(31): error #6323: This label is not defined in this scoping unit.      [40]
        DO 40 IOUT = 1,12
-----------^
wallcontrol.f(69): error #6790: This is an invalid statement; an END [PROGRAM]     statement is required.
       end module wallforcing
-------^
wallcontrol.f(69): error #6785: This name does not match the unit name.   [WALLF   ORCING]
       end module wallforcing
------------------^
compilation aborted for wallcontrol.f (code 1)
```

What's wrong in the code? Coming from other programming languages, I find weird how FORTRAN messes up with blank spaces. Is there any good tutorial on this topic?

Comment: Do those labels `20`, `40`, `60`, etc., sit in columns 5 and 6 of the code you have?  That would be bad.

Comment: I put the 20 in the first column and now the error refers to the F in FORMAT

Comment: And you put the `F` in the seventh column?

Comment: Welcome. Please **always** when showing any errors, include the command that caused the errors. Including the compiler name and the source file name. Fortunately, the Intel compiler can be recognized here, but only by those who know it well. Take also the welcome [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your statement labels are in wrong columns. Please read the comments others already posted and the answers in the link.